# Routeprovider params angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I'm newbie in AngularJs, and I have a problem.

```
$routeProvider.when(baseURL + "Game/:Id?", {
    controller: "gameController",
    templateUrl: "Game/index.html",
});
```

I want to get params "Id" to load game, and all game will load only in one page index.html. But when I go to url: Game/1, it don't load page index.html, instead "Page not found (404)". 
So how to dot it, please help me. Thanks so much!

Comment: what's `baseURL` and are your files in that location?

Answer (score 1):

remove the baseurl and try it like.

```
$routeProvider.when( "/Game/:Id", {
    controller: "gameController",
    templateUrl: "Game/index.html",
});
```

check it http://plnkr.co/edit/p04gHtGDyRH3fWOomzqu?p=preview

Comment: You have to prefix the path parameter with `/`. I've tried to edit your answer to correct it but it seems you didn't accept my edit. Try to check/compare your **plunkr** with your sample code.